# change jquery submit from get to post

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm using the following jQuery in a Confluence page (using code that allows you to insert HTML in Confluence pages) to fill some fields in an external HTML page with what users enter into input fields.

Now I want to change it to use the `post` method instead of `get`.

Here's the code: First, assign an ID called `input2` to a built-in Confluence input field:

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".search-macro-medium .search-macro-query input").attr("id","input2");
  });
```

Then, the code that appends the input to the URL:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $('#srsButton').click(function(e) {  
  var inputvalue = $("#input2").val();
   if
    ($('#input2').val()==""){
      $('.alertReq, .asterisk').css('visibility', 'visible');
   } 
   else 
     window.open("http://example.com/cgi?ticket_type=15984&F_334133=x&subject="+inputvalue);
 });
});
```

This all works, and I also know how to use `post` in a form that I create, like this:

```
<form style="margin-bottom:200px" action="http://example.com/cgi?ticket_type=15984 method="post">
Confirmation <input type="text" name="F_334133"><br>
Subject <input type="text" name="Subject"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Combining the two is puzzling me though. Maybe it's simpler than I think.

The main thing is that I can't create my own form, but need to pick up what's inserted in the `.search-macro-medium .search-macro-query input` form instead.

UPDATE:

Putting this here to not clog up comments:

Thanks for the responses. I could possibly sell people on going back to having it in the same window, what's more important is that I can't just create my own form but have to use this field that's inserted in the page by a Confluence "macro".

I have to style and manipulate these dynamically as they load on the page, identify the elements and so on. For example `.search-macro-medium .search-macro-query input` is actually a search field that I'm using to do two things: One being the built-in Confluence auto-suggest functionality that will drop down a list of suggested links, and the second being that I pick up what the user enters into it and use that to populate a form elsewhere.

I could re-create the entire input field but then I'd lose the auto-suggest functionality. Kind of a hybrid world, creating some of the HTML myself but having to rely on these little widgets also.

Oh and yes, I have no control over the destination page; same company, but -- would be complicated to get it changed.

UPDATE II

I'm accepting Arkantos' answer because I basically used the hidden form idea to make this work, though in a slightly different way. For the other part that I mentioned, capturing text from the built-in Confluence dropdowns, here's the code that worked including the `.clone().append(' | ').text());` part that allows me to get all the drop down li text, post it in a form field, and insert separators in the list.

```
  // Show the suggested match heading when anything typed in field
  // Capture dropdown titles
   $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('form.aui').on('keyup', showHead);
     function showHead() {
     $('.suggestHead').delay(500).fadeIn(300);
     $('.alertReq, .asterisk').css('visibility', 'hidden');
     var dropdownText = (AJS.$( "div.searchContainer2  a.content-type-page span em" ).clone().append(' | ').text());
     $('#capture').val( dropdownText );
     var inputvalue = $("#input2").val( );
     $( '#describe' ).val( inputvalue );
    };    
   });
```

Comment: `$.post("http://example.com/cgi", {subject : $('search-macro-query input').val()})`

Comment: You cannot send a post request with `window.open()`. Is it mandatory that you should always open a new separate window to get the updated content ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no direct way to do this from client side. Usually when we want to redirect to some other page sending some parameters, we'll ask the server to return a page with nothing but a form containing our request parameters as hidden parameters.

But in your case, as your planning to do it in from client side, you need to have a form with hidden parameters like below.

**In your Main Page**

```
<form action="http://example.com/cgi" method="post" id="myForm">
   <input type="hidden" name="ticket_type" value="15984" >
   <input type="hidden" name="F_334133" value="x">
   <input type="hidden" name="Subject" value="sdfd">
</form>
```

And to the difficult part, that you should ALWAYS open a new window to show data, first you need to open a window with empty url, append your hidden form to that new window's document and submit the form.

**In your Main Page JS**

```
  var newWindow = window.open('','myWindow');
  var hiddenForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
  newWindow.document.body.appendChild(hiddenForm);
  hiddenForm.submit();
```

Here's a [bin](http://jsbin.com/moporuniva/1/edit?html,js,output) to illustrate the idea. On click of a button, it will open an empty window first, then do an invisible form submit to google.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the form submit using ajax.

There is a method in jQuery `$.ajax`
See this: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/